# Multiple Max Criteria in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've been using a query that returns the maximum number in the ballNumber field when the value in the inningsNo field is 1.

Now I would like to add a field that also returns returns the maximum number in the ballNumber field when the value in the inningsNo field is 2.

I've followed the same logic as before but it doesn't work for some reason.

[image]

Can anyone point out the issue?

Thanks

Comment: rob, this won't work because you are asking it to return data where inningsNo is equal to both 1 and 2, which will never happen!! You will probably need to create a second query to get the value where inningsNo=2

Comment: Write '1 or 2' as a criteria in the 1st col. Remove 3d col

Answer (score 0):

That should be what you are looking for:

```sql
Select
  T1.MaxBallNumber As Max1,
  T2.MaxBallNumber As Max2
From
  (Select Max(ballNumber) As MaxBallNumber From BallByBall Where InningsNo=1) As T1,
  (Select Max(ballNumber) As MaxBallNumber From BallByBall Where InningsNo=2) As T2
```